# How to skip the header row in CSV file while loading data in DB2

Tags: import, db2, db2-luw

Its a very big CSV file so am not able to open and edit the first row. I need to load the data without the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

`db2 'import from EMP_SAMPLE.csv of del skipcount 1 INSERT INTO EMP_DET (FIRST_NME, SECOND_NME)'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SKIPCOUNT 1` as modifier. This should work at least for `IMPORT`.

See here for the details:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html#r0008304__d80071e2062

Answer (score 0):

If using LOAD there is no option to skip the first row, so either let it get rejected and set `WARNINGCOUNT 2`, or delete it after it gets loaded, or pipe your data thru e.g. `tail -n +2` to skip the first row (and load from a named pipe to avoid landing the data if you wish).
You could also try the INGEST utility, or IMPORT as Henrik suggests